# How long does it take to solve a Olympiad maths problem?

Tags: soft-question, contest-math

I am currently practicing for the AMC12, and I am getting frustrated. For each problem, if I do find the solution, it takes over an hour, and when I cannot, I flip over to the solution page. I want to know if this is normal when practicing for the Maths Olympiad.

Comment: The question in the title obviously varies a lot by question and person, maybe even by the day the person is doing the question and whether they had gotten enough sleep the previous day.

Comment: Some math competition problems took me 2 months. It was the best feeling ever solving them.

Comment: In each of the two IMO exams, you have 4.5 hours for three problems, and not everybody solves them all, so one hour would not be too bad

Comment: Have a look at the responses here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3382253/496634 , which are also about looking at solutions, but for analysis homework questions as oppsed to contest problems. Still, you might find the answers helpful.

Comment: It can easily take months for me, although I am working with such only in my very little spare time on the bus for example